# How Do I Fix This TypeError In React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, reactstrap

I am struggling and in need of help! I'm extremely new to **React** - and I'm busy doing this practice assignment for a course that I'm taking to learn it, but I am running into the same sort of problem over and over again and I cannot seem to get it right.

I do not need you to complete my assignment, but any hint or **directions**/****feedback**** on my code on where I am going wrong and what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated. Oof, I'm just so tired of not finding the solution on Google/forums, and my React skills are fairly novice so I can't really identify the problem without the help of some super cool React experts out there! Thank you very much in advance. :)

***I keep on getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined***

> **Full Source Code Here:** https://github.com/christinec-dev/react_new

***The overall end goal of my application is as follows (added here for perspective reasons):***

**Task 1:**

- A new DishdetailComponent has been added to your React application.
- Included the DishDetail into your MenuComponent's view to show the selected dish.
- Passing the selected dish as props to the DishDetail Component.
- Used the appropriate Bootstrap classes to the card so that it occupies the entire row for xs and sm screen sizes, and 5 columns for md screens and above.
- Used the appropriate Bootstrap classes to the div containing the list of comments so that it occupies the entire row for xs and sm screen sizes, and 5 columns for md screens and above.

**Task 2:**

- Used the Card component to display the details of the dish.

**Task 3:**

- Included a list of comments about the dish into the dishdetail view.

```js
----------------------------------------- menuComponent.js

//package imports
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import bootrap components from reactstrap library
//NOTE: The media query returns a CSS style 
import { Card, CardImgOverlay, CardImg, CardBody, CardText, CardTitle  } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';


//creates Menu component
class Menu extends Component {
    
    //define a constructor for it
    constructor(props) {

        //Props is read-only and are used to pass data, whereas state is for managing data and can be modified by its own component

        //required when you create a component in react
        super(props);
        
        //when document is loaded no card has been selected by default
        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        };
    }

    //when dishg is clicked, it will render details of dish
    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({selectedDish: dish});
    }

   //if dish is clicked it will show card details, else nothing
   renderDish(dish) {
    if(dish != null) {
        return(
        <Card>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                </CardBody>
        </Card>
        );
        } else {
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    //return a value or function that will be called
    render() {

        //will iterate (map) over the dishes list and return each key (item) uniquely
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            // This will create the layout of the menu items by displaying the image, name and -description- of each menu item
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                      {/* When clicked on, it will run event function*/} 
                      <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish.id, dish.comments)}>
                            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />

                            <CardImgOverlay body className="ml-5">
                                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                            </CardImgOverlay>
                        </Card>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
        //This will return a menu list that will be defined
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                 {/* This will return the menu items */}             
                    {menu}
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                 {/* This will return the clicked card dish items when clicked */} 
                 <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">          
                    {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)},
                </div> 
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">          
                    <DishDetail dishes={this.state.dishes} />
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

//exports it for use in other files
export default Menu;
```

```css
-------------------DishdetailComponent.js

//package imports
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import bootrap components from reactstrap library
//NOTE: The media query returns a CSS style 


//creates Dishdetail component
class DishDetail extends Component {
    
    //define a constructor for it
    constructor(props) {
        //Props is read-only and are used to pass data, whereas state is for managing data and can be modified by its own component

        //required when you create a component in react
        super(props);
        
        //when document is loaded no card has been selected by default
        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null,
            comments: null
        };
    }

    onDishSelect(comments) {
        this.setState({comments: comments});
    }

   //if dish is clicked it will show card comments, else nothing
   
    renderComments(comments) {
        if (comments != null){
                return (
                        <ul key={comments.id} className="list-unstyled">
                            <li className="comment">{comments.comment}</li>
                            <li className="author"> {comments.author}</li>
                            <li className="date"> {comments.date}</li>
                        </ul>   
                )       
        }
        else {
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
        }
    }

    //return a value or function that will be called
    render() {

    //will iterate (map) over the dishes list and return each key (item) uniquely
    const details = this.props.comments.map((comments) => {
            return (         
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">  
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <h4>Comments</h4>
                        <div>{comments}</div>  
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        //This will return a menu list that will be defined
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                 {/* This will return the menu items */}             
                    {details}
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                 {/* This will return the clicked card dish items when clicked */}             
                 {this.renderComments(this.state.selectedDish)},
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
  

      
//exports it for use in other files
export default DishDetail;
```

```html
----------------------------------------- App.js

//package and component imports
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavbarBrand, Navbar } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './components/menuComponent';
import DishDetail from './components/DishdetailComponent';

import './App.css';
import {DISHES} from './shared/dishes';

//creates Menu component
class App extends Component {
    
  //define a constructor for it
  constructor (props) {

    //Props is read-only and are used to pass data, whereas state is for managing data and can be modified by its own component

    //required when you create a component in react
    super(props);

   
    //when document is loaded no card has been selected by default
        this.state = {
          dishes: DISHES,
          selectedDish: null,
          comments: null
      };
  }

  //when dishg is clicked, it will render details of dish
  onDishSelect(dish) {
      this.setState({ selectedDish: dish});
      
  }


  render () {
    return (    
    //To create html structures in React we always define it via the className strucutre
    <div>
      
      {/* This will create a layour based on our individual component files. For example, if we have a navbarComponent file, then we just import it from there and insert it here, without having to code the whole thing. */}
      <Navbar color="primary" dark expand="md">
        <div className="container">
        <NavbarBrand href="/"> Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
  
     {/* The Menu component from the menuComponent.js file is rendered here and displayed when the index.js is loaded */}
     <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
    </div>
  );
  }
}

//exports it for use in other files
export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: It'd be better if you share with us the code via a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hey, will Github do? => https://github.com/christinec-dev/react_new

Comment: @SanaMumtaz it is ***always*** preferrable to have a [mcve] available in the question. Future users should not have to visit an off-site resource to see the code. Stack Overflow has [a snippet feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so the code can be embedded and ran directly here, so there is hardly a case where an off-site snippet editor is needed.

Comment: @Christine as I said, we need the code here in the question as a [mcve]. The less code you show (and this more focused on the problem), the better. Don't put links to a repository with *all* the code. See: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by myself after reading some documentation. It turns out I had to remove the renderDish(dish) function from the menuComponent.js file and place it in the DishdetailComponent.js file.

To solve the

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined problem

I did the following:

```
 //if dish is clicked it will show dish comments, else nothing
renderComments(array) {
    //if dish array is not equal to null, display comments in half grid
    if (array.length != 0) {
        return (
            //col-12 for sm and xs, and col-5 for md and lg screens with margin @ 1
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                {/* Displays the comment title, and details of author, date and comment */}
                <h4>Comments</h4>                  
                {/* //will iterate (map) over the comments list and return each key (item) uniquely */}
                { array.map (comment => (
                    <ul className="list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                            <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                            <p><i> - {comment.author} </i>, {comment.date}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                ))
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
    //if the dish contains nothing, show nothing
    else {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is preatty clear, this.props.comments or this.props.dishes are undefined.

You are trying to access the property .map of undefined element.

Basically add a check to be sure that this.props.comments and this.props.dishes exist and are arrays, or you can add a loader or you can add question point this.props.comments?.map(... and this.props.dishes?.map(...

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried the question mark solution - it gave me a failed to compile error. Could this be undefined because I am referencing my array incorrectly or it just doesn't find it? (My array is in the Github above as dishes.js if you wanna have a look).

Answer (score 0):

`src\App.js Line 4:8:  'DishDetail' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars`

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add `// eslint-disable-next-line to the line before`.